# Xpath : How to find a node which is not descendant from a specific node

Tags: javascript, dom, xpath, xquery

Example, I have an XML doc like this

```
a[@class="wrong]
 ...
   b
    c 
d
 ...
   b
    c <= this one
```

**I would like to select the second //b/c without taking the //b/c from the first part with @class="wrong".** 
And there are some unknown node between unwanted node and the //b/c.
And I do not know wich is the exact markup with non desired class.

So I try `//*[not(contains(@class,'wrong'))]/b/c`
but it doesn't work because if there is at least one node in '...' without this class, the first b/c is also returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
//b[not(ancestor::*[contains(@class,'wrong')])]/c
```